# Use nullable/nonnull for property that already have default value

Tags: ios, objective-c

I know the way to use `nonnull` and `nullable`is

```
nonnull: the value won’t be nil; bridges to a regular reference.
nullable: the value can be nil; bridges to an optional.
```

But in my case, the `titleColor` seems like both `nullable` and `nonnull`. It is `nullable` because we may not need to set value and it `nonnull` because it always has the default value. Do I understand correct and in my case, what should I choose nullable or nonnull?

```
// IN .h file 
@property(nonatomic, strong) UIColor *titleColor;
// @property(nonatomic, strong, nullable) UIColor *titleColor;


// IN .m file
-(UIColor *)titleColor{
    if(!_titleColor){
        _titleColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    }
    return _titleColor;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `nonnull` if the setter won't accept `nil` and the getter won't ever return `nil`.

Use `nullable` if the setter will accept `nil` or if the getter will ever return `nil`.

Keep in mind that Objective-C won't really care what you actually do.

So if in Swift you would use an optional, then make it `nullable`, otherwise make it `nonnull`.

Comment: but in my case now, the setter both will and won't accept `nil`, and the getter    won't ever return nil. so what should I choose?

Comment: In other words the setter "will" accept `nil`. You can't say it will and it won't. It either will or it won't. Since you state the setter will accept `nil` you should use `nullable`.

Comment: so we will use `nullable` or `nonnull` depend on the setter method and don't care about getter

Comment: You care about both. If either allows `nil`, then you must use `nullable`.

Comment: sorry, I don't understand here. If I care both setter and getter it will look like. my `titleColor` will accept `nil` => so I should use `nullable`. but the getter won't ever return nil => so I should use `nonnull` ? Then If I care both, it will not solve my problem

Comment: You look at both the setter and getter. If either the setter can accept `nil` or the getter can return `nil`, then you use `nullable`. That's it. Nice and simple. Since, in your case, the setter can accept `nil`, you must use `nullable`.

Comment: why you don't care about getter won't ever return `nil`?

Comment: I think we have a language barrier here. Think of this as an `if` statement: `if (setterCanAcceptNil || getterCanReturnNil) { use nullable } else { use nonnull }`. As you know, such a statement will be true if either or both sides of the `||` are true.

Comment: For the benefit of future readers: "Keep in mind that Objective-C won't really care what you actually do" ... Yeah, but if you use the static analyzer, it will analyze the code and warn you if it finds paths where a potentially `nil` value was passed to a `nonnull` parameter. So it does bear _some_ utility, albeit not strictly enforced like Swift: Imagine you have a routine that cannot accept `nil`, if you mark it appropriately, the static analyzer can warn you if you might have problematic scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

**Use nullable**

**null_unspecified**: bridges to a Swift implicitly-unwrapped optional. This is the default.

**nonnull:** the value won’t be nil; bridges to a regular reference.

**nullable**: the value can be nil; bridges to an optional.

**null_resettable**: the value can never be nil when read, but you can set it to nil to reset it. Applies to properties only.

Code example:

```
 // property style
@property (nonatomic, strong, null_resettable) NSString *name;

// pointer style
+ (NSArray<NSView *> * _Nullable)interestingObjectsForKey:(NSString * _Nonnull)key;

// these two are equivalent!
 @property (nonatomic, strong, nullable) NSString *identifier1;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString * _Nullable identifier2;
```

Good description more: https://swiftunboxed.com/interop/objc-nullability-annotations/

From http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AttributeReference.html#nullability-attributes

> The nullability (type) qualifiers express whether a value of a given pointer type can be null (the _Nullable qualifier), doesn’t have a defined meaning for null (the _Nonnull qualifier), or for which the purpose of null is unclear (the _Null_unspecified qualifier). Because nullability qualifiers are expressed within the type system, they are more general than the nonnull and returns_nonnull attributes, allowing one to express (for example) a nullable pointer to an array of nonnull pointers. Nullability qualifiers are written to the right of the pointer to which they apply.

Apple swift doc: https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=25

Comment: thank you for providing helpful document, but can see check my case now, what should I choose in nonnull or nullable for  `titleColor` property